# External Python Scripts and Django Virtual Env

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, virtualenv

I run an external script from my Django app using subprocess this way:

```
class ExecutePythonFileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # Execute script
        script_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '/Code/zenet/zenet/workers/stats_scraper.py')
        subprocess.call(['python', script_path])
        # Return response
        return HttpResponse("Executed!")
```

I would need to execute it through the Django virtual environment though, how could I proceed?

Comment: what's the role of the script? maybe it would be easier to convert it to a Django management command and run it that way.

Comment: This a script that scrape data from a website. I'm going to have about 15 scripts of this kind that will get data and populate a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two options,

Option #1:

- Upgrade the script into a management command
- Use django.core.management.call_command to run the script
- This way Django would take care of spawning the subprocess if needed and related stuff

Option #2:

- Proceed with the same approach
- Update the view as follows

```py
import sys

class ExecutePythonFileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # Execute script
        script_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '/Code/zenet/zenet/workers/stats_scraper.py')
        subprocess.call([sys.executable, script_path])
        # Return response
        return HttpResponse("Executed!")
```